# Website is not working in safari private browsing

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, local-storage

My website is built using Jquery Mobile and Knockoutjs. Everything works fine in mobile browsers with private browsing except for Safari with private browsing on iOS.

Anybody faced similar problems?

Comment: "Not working"? Can you perhaps clarify what is wrong?

Comment: site does not load , i am guessing it throwed some javascript error which is stopping the site to load, i don`t have mac handy to check the site in debug mode

Comment: So find a Mac and debug the site using the web inspector (phone and desktop)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does your website depend on local storage in the device (html5) or on cookies? Then you must have a fallback solution for that.

Comment: Yeah we do use local storage , so local storage does not work on safari?

Comment: @SharePointKID You should always check if certain features are available before using them.

Comment: When you use private browsing then local storage and cookies have many limitation from the OS. And check the features before you use them.

Comment: Thanks both for your inputs and suggestions.